# MySQL Query with PHP function compare?

Tags: php, mysql, function

What I want to do is while executing MySQL query, passing column data into a PHP function and comparing the result with WHERE clause...

Something like that, I have the slug() function which I wrote in PHP and my query will be something like;

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug(author) = "james-taylor";
```

So the query will select "author" column and pass it to slug() function and compare returning data with "james-taylor".

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way to use a PHP function directly in mysql.

You would need to use mysql string functions to duplicate your slug function in mysql. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Another option would be to have a field named "slug" and to use the php function to generate slugs for all of your records in the table.  Then you can say "select * from articles where slug = 'james-taylor';

```
$slug = slug('James Taylor');
$sql = "select * from articles where slug = '{$slug}'";
```

Comment: Yep. Of course this can be brittle if you ever want to update/change/correct an author's name, which is why most sites use ID+slug in URLs rather than just slug.

Comment: Recommend you use a query parameter instead of interpolating `$slug` into the SQL string.

Comment: having a field named "slug" is the good and easier option, I'll use that idea, thank you very much :)

Comment: Dooltaz: can you please explain what is the meaning of the curly brackets used in this line ->"select * from articles where slug = '{$slug}'"; usually I would write such a statement as: "select * from articles where slug = '" . $slug . "'"; - Just curious.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That’s not possible. But you can [create a function in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html) that does the same as your PHP function.