# how do i use SQL value as parameter function inside SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, function, parameters, pdo

If I have a function inside an SQL query, for example if I have comments and I want to verify inside the SQL if that comment have a minimum character to show in list:

```
$bdd->query('SELECT id, comment FROM comments WHERE count > '. count_chars("id").' ORDER BY time');
```

So the problem is: how can I use the id as parameter for this function?

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406257/mysql-query-with-php-function-compare and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750891/a-php-function-inside-a-mysql-query

Comment: which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? According to the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php), count_chars(string) returns an array. I'm assuming the count column on your SQL table is of type INT. Using `>` to compare an INT with an array doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you looking for the SQL function CHAR_LENGTH()? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a PHP function inside an SQL query, to set the results of the query.
However, PHP is *not* involved in the querying process. it only sends the query to the DB, where it is actually processed. So using a PHP function inside a query will always result in a static value, that won't change as the DB iterates over the rows.
Therefore, you need to use **an SQL function**, namely, LENGTH().

e.g. to choose only comments that have more than 50 chars:

```
 $bdd->query('SELECT id, comment FROM comments WHERE LENGTH(comment)>50 ORDER BY time') //
```

NOTE: The function might be called LEN, depending on your MYSQL version